# How do I use a Maybe (List a) in a map?

Tags: elm

I have a weird situation that I just can't figure out.

```elm
type alias Schedule =
    { name : String
    , display : String
    , interval : Maybe Int
    , events : Maybe (List Event)
    }


type alias Event =
    { schedule : Maybe String
    , interval : Maybe Int
    , hook : String
    , args : List ( String, String )
    , timestamp : Int
    , seconds_due : Int
    }

setScheduledEventDueNow : Event -> Schedule -> Schedule
setScheduledEventDueNow event schedule =
    case schedule.events of
        Just events ->
            { schedule | events = List.map (setMatchedEventDueNow event) events }

        Nothing ->
            schedule
```

There may or may not be a `List` of `Events` in the `Schedule`, so it's set as `events : Maybe (List Event)`.

In response to an action on a known `Event` I want to run through the events on a schedule if it has any, and potentially return an updated list of events for the schedule.

However, I'm getting the following error:

```elm
-- TYPE MISMATCH ----------------------------------------- src/elm/CronPixie.elm

The 1st and 2nd branches of this `case` produce different types of values.

373|     case schedule.events of
374|         Just events ->
375|             { schedule | events = List.map (setMatchedEventDueNow event) events }
376| 
377|         Nothing ->
378|>            schedule

The 1st branch has this type:

    { a | events : List Event }

But the 2nd is:

    { a | events : Maybe (List Event) }

Hint: All branches in a `case` must have the same type. So no matter which one
we take, we always get back the same type of value.

Detected errors in 1 module.
```

My beginner brain thought because I had verified that there really was a list of events with the `case` statement, that all should be good to map it.

But the compiler is recognising that it's a simple `List.map` with no chance of a Maybe, so naturally complains about the difference between what is returned by the two branches of the `case`.

Any idea how I get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the list using Just

```elm
Just events ->
    { schedule | events = Just <| List.map (setMatchedEventDueNow event) events }
```

You could write the whole function more succinctly by using `Maybe.map`, which returns `Nothing` if the list of events is already `Nothing`, and maps to the underlying list using the provided function otherwise:

```elm
setScheduledEventDueNow : Event -> Schedule -> Schedule
setScheduledEventDueNow event schedule =
  { schedule | events = Maybe.map (List.map <| setMatchedEventDueNow event) schedule.events }
```

Comment: This will work. More fundamental question is whether you really need the `Maybe (List a)` type in this case? If you have no events on your schedule (i.e. nothing in your list), then wouldn't an empty list `[]` serve your purpose?  Then your events can simply be of type `List Event` which would save much `Maybe.map` and `case` statements. I find that I only need the `Maybe` type for non-list stuff, e.g. a `Maybe Int`, or a `Maybe Date` where `Nothing` means that the variable is empty.

Comment: That depends on your business requirements, but most often I'd think it's just fine. The Maybe becomes unnecessary when an empty list suits your needs

Comment: Unfortunately the data is coming from a PHP backend that may not include the `events` section in a `Schedule` under certain circumstances. I could I suppose add the empty list instead, that's not a bad idea. I also considered using a `Dict` for the `Schedule`, I might investigate that some time in the future.

Comment: You could still use the empty list idea regardless of whether php sends it or not. You would just need a json decoder to decode the absence of events as an empty list (assuming semantic equivalence of the two in your circumstance)

Comment: Yeah, that what I was meaning with "I could I suppose add the empty list instead, that's not a bad idea.", add it in via the decoder if not present. Thanks for all the help Chad.